# Query to output values which are not present in table

Tags: sql, oracle

Need help in Oracle query

Requirement:

I have 5 rows in a table lets say ID = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Requirement is as such that user may pass any value as input and if that value is not there in table then query should return me the value which is not present.

Ex:
    1. If user passes 9 then Oracle query should return the output as 9
    2. If user passes 1,2,10 then Oracle query should return the output as 10

as 9 and 10 in above example are not in table.

I am using following query but not getting result.

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ID NOT IN
(SELECT ID 
FROM TABLE_NAME where ID NOT in (1,2,10))
```

Comment: @V4Vedanta - these r simply dummy value used in example... nothing else... my req'nt is to check if the value that is passed is available n table ... if not then display that value.

Comment: How does the user pass "1,2,10"? As a string or as an array of values or as content of another table? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table z (id number);
Table created.

SQL> insert into z values (1);
1 row created.
SQL> insert into z values (2);
1 row created.
SQL> insert into z values (3);
1 row created.
SQL> insert into z values (4);
1 row created.
SQL> insert into z values (5);
1 row created.

SQL> select 10 id from dual
  2  minus
  3  select id from z;

    ID
----------
    10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested table as input:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE table_name (ID NUMBER NOT NULL); 

Table created

SQL> INSERT INTO table_name (SELECT ROWNUM FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5); 

5 rows inserted

SQL> CREATE TYPE tab_number AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  2  / 

Type created

SQL> SELECT *
  2    FROM TABLE(tab_number(1,2,10)) x
  3   WHERE x.column_value NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table_name);

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
          10
```